# Функции и переменные в SQL

Tags: sql

Увидел в презентации на уроке:

```
СУБД                Функция/переменная
Access              NOW()
DB2                 CURRENT_DATE
MySQL               CURRENT_DATE()
Oracle              SYSDATE
PostgreSQL          CURRENT_DATE
SQL Server          GETDATE()
SQLite              date('now')
```

`NOW()`, `GETDATE()`, `CURRENT_DATE()`, `date('now')` - это функции?

`CURRENT_DATE`, `SYSDATE` - это переменные?

Comment: Не переменные. Ключевые слова, которые работают как функции

Comment: Извиняюсь, посмотрел следующий слайд и там расписано всё было, моя невнимательность.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если это точная цитата из презентации, то докладчик не заслуживает добрых слов. По крайней мере в той части, по которой он показал сию таблицу без пояснений. Ибо:

1. Часть из приведённых конструкций даст только дату, часть - и дату, и время. Собрать их в одну таблицу и стыдливо умолчать о разнице - неверно.
2. На некоторых СУБД показанная конструкция - не единственная. Например, в MySQL для получения текущей даты (без компоненты времени) могут использоваться:

   ```
   CURDATE()
   CURRENT_DATE()
   CURRENT_DATE
   ```

Это всё - синонимы. И я не возьмусь сказать, кто кому является обёрткой...

---

Более того - время тоже бывает разное... например, в том же MySQL функция NOW() вернёт точное время начала выполнения запроса, а SYSDATE() - точное время выполнения самой функции в рамках выполнения запроса. Что, очевидно, вовсе не одно и то же, особенно если запрос выполняется достаточно продолжительное время, и функция вызывается в разных местах запроса.

```
mysql> SET @@cte_max_recursion_depth := 1000000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> WITH RECURSIVE
    -> cte1 AS (SELECT NOW(3) `cte1.now`, SYSDATE(3) `cte1.sysdate`),
    -> cte2 AS (SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT num+1 FROM cte2 WHERE num < 1000000),
    -> cte3 AS (SELECT MAX(cte2.num), NOW(3) `cte3.now`, SYSDATE(3) `cte3.sysdate` FROM cte2)
    -> SELECT `cte1.now`, `cte1.sysdate`, `cte3.now`, `cte3.sysdate`, NOW(3) `query.now`, SYSDATE(3) `query.sysdate`
    -> FROM cte1, cte2, cte3
    -> LIMIT 1;
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| cte1.now                | cte1.sysdate            | cte3.now                | cte3.sysdate            | query.now               | query.sysdate           |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2019-08-29 16:44:02.167 | 2019-08-29 16:44:02.168 | 2019-08-29 16:44:02.167 | 2019-08-29 16:44:04.645 | 2019-08-29 16:44:02.167 | 2019-08-29 16:44:04.794 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (2.75 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

`CURRENT_DATE` и `SYSDATE`, это не переменные, а ключевые слова, за которыми скрывается вызов соответствующих функций.